# How can I displaying user image?

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore, user-input

I displaying user profile picture and I have 3 options that can be displayed. The first one is the current picked image, that's picked from camera or library and if there is an image it will be displayed. And then user can safe it so it will be also displayed when user restart the app and in that case I displaying the saved image . And then there's my third option if there's no picture saved and also no picture selected at the moment then I will displaying a default image, thats in my assets . Here's my question how do I doing this because this default picture will also be displayed ,if user delete the current saved picture so if he change back to "NO picture taken" then again the default picture will be displayed. But how do I implement this in my code ?The picture is saving in storage as a file and also in firestore as a url
Heres my Circle avatar for dislplaying saving image and also selected image before saving.

```
   Container(
                                      child: Center(
                                              child:
                                            CircleAvatar(
                                              radius: 70,
                                              
                                              foregroundImage: _pickedImage!=null? FileImage(_pickedImage): NetworkImage ( userData.url),
                                            ),
                              ),
                                          decoration: new BoxDecoration(
                                            shape: BoxShape.circle,
```

here's my method for that:

```
   onPressed: () async {
                if (_formKey.currentState.validate()) {
                  final ref= FirebaseStorage.instance.ref().child('user_profile_pictures').child(user.uid+'.jpg');
                  await ref.putFile(_pickedImage);
                  final url = await ref.getDownloadURL();
                  _curenturl= url;

                  String authError =
                      await DatbaseService(uid: user.uid).updateUserData(
                    _currentusername ?? userData.user,
                    _currentfullname ?? userData.fullname,
                    _currentemail ?? userData.email,
                    _currentpassword ?? userData.password,
                          _curenturl ??userData.url,

                  );
                  if (authError != null) {
```

And here's my pressed method for setting the current url to null and also the userData.url

```
      onTap: () {

                 DatbaseService(uid: user.uid).updateUserData(
                   _currentusername ?? userData.user,
                   _currentfullname ?? userData.fullname,
                   _currentemail ?? userData.email,
                   _currentpassword ?? userData.password,
                   _curenturl =null,
            );
                Navigator.pop(context);
              },
```

So as you can see im setting the url again to null. IM doing this so that there's no saved picture anymore,. And then I wanna displaying the default image from my assets .I tried to update my current url bwith that picture but the url is a string and my picture a assets image .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try as well as my code:

```
  ClipRRect(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(60),
            child: Container(
              height: 100,
              width: 100,
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                color: Colors.grey.shade300,
              ),
              child: image != null
                  ? Image.file(
                      image,
                      fit: BoxFit.cover,
                    )
                  : networkImg != null && networkImg != ''
                      ? Image.network(
                          networkImg,
                          fit: BoxFit.cover,
                        )
                      : Image.asset(
// Your image path is here when image is no available.
),
            ),
          ),
```

Please let me know it's working or not.

Comment: It work like before but when im adding this line AssetImage('assets/profilepictureer.png'),   instead of the Container it says type 'AssetImage' is not a subtype of type 'Widget?'

Comment: @newuser122 I have edited my code so please try now.You need to use Image.asset property.

Comment: perfect it works thank you, but how do it delete also the file in storage ?